# how to convert network state from blocked to connected

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to establish tcp socket connection when my app is in background, before I start connect to server, I checked the network state with the code below

```
 ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
 NetworkInfo.DetailedState state = info.getDetailedState();
```

and find the `state` is `BLOCKED`, which will cause failure for the tcp connection.

I was wondering is there any method to change network state from `Blocked` to `Connected` state? Any advice is appreciated, thanks in advance.

PS: I am working on MIUI rom, other roms may not have this issue.

Comment: `trying to establish tcp socket connection when my app is in background, before I start connect to server`. ???? How would you establish a connection without connecting to a server? Your description makes no sense.

Comment: On my device network requests don't fail in the blocked state. Is there some documentation about this state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply force a change of state. This state indicates that the device is simply not allowed to use the network, even though it might be connected. The BLOCKED state typically means that the user of the device has chosen to not allow background data access. (Maybe they have limited data on their plan and need to control access to data usage.)

Comment: The point is I can access this network when app in foreground, only background app is limited to use. And network type is wifi, not data.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I just said. The user is given a choice about how they want data to be used on their device.  You can't override that decision.

Comment: I experienced the same issue on my own device. I implemented a widget and the update process sometimes failed because network state is BLOCKED. But I don´t want this and I didn´t configure something like this for my device. And it occurs only sometimes. So, I would like to understand why Android sets the network to BLOCKED. And how I could get informed when the networked is no longer blocked.